# How can I create topology that is going to stand up to bevel and subd modifiers?

Tags: topology

I was about to model a game console and this shape came up and I just froze ... how can I create a topology that is going to stand up to bevel and subd mods.

This is my first pass... curious if someone would be interested in presenting a better method.

Thank you all so much!
[image]

[image]

Comment: A good start is to avoid ngons (faces with more than 4 vertices)

Comment: Do you have a reference photo? It would help if we could see the shape you're trying to achieve